# Search for multiple keys and values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to search in an array for multiple keys with the same value.
Example: I have a object with 19 rows:

```
1: {
    numbers: [], 
    count: 5, 
    check: {
        0: true, 
        1: false, 
        2: true, 
        3: false, 
        4: true, 
        5: false, 
        6: true, 
        7: false, 
        8: true, 
    }
},
2: {
    numbers: [], 
    count: 5, 
    check: {
        0: false, 
        1: true, 
        2: false, 
        3: true,     
        4: false, 
        5: true, 
        6: false, 
        7: false, 
        8: true, 
    }
},
```

I want to return a row when `1: true` and `6: false`. Here's what I have made up to now:

```
for (y in rows[x]['check']) {
    if (rows[x]['check'][y] == false) {
        var correctRow =  rows[x]['numbers'];
    }
}
```

This is looping through the rows I can search only for 1 key with value. But I need to search for 2 keys with specific value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays, there are no arrays in your question. There are only objects. Arrays in JavaScript have *numeric indexes* and are created using `[]`, not `{}`.

Comment: you also can't have "rows" in a JavaScript object, it's an object not a table

Comment: Removed jquery tag, this question has nothing to do with jquery.

Comment: @meagar i think he means an array of objects. Maybe. I'm a bit confused as well

Comment: I will change the title

Comment: @AdemAk you wouldn't need a loop on `check`. You know what positions of the array you need to check so just check their values. `if (rows[x]['check'][1] == true && rows[x]['check'][6] == false)` You would only need a loop on `rows`.

Comment: @SpencerMay Omg that is what i was searching for. Really thanx ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but the following javascript will search your starting object and push child objects that match the criteria .check[1] == true and .check[6] == false into a new array, assuming 'obj' is the object from your post:

```
var correct = [];

for (row in Object.keys(obj)) {

   var surr_row = Number(row) + 1,
       temp = obj[surr_row];

       if (temp.check['1'] == true && temp.check['6'] == false) {
          correct.push(temp);
       }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's what you are looking for though...